# Sprite-Kit Obstacle Game - PhysicsBody issues

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have created a simple 2D arcade game using SpriteKit and I am trying to add a scoring system.Basically the game is a square sprite which has to jump over various obstacles.

What I have tried so far is creating an SKSpriteNode() which adds +1 to the score counter label when it contacts the player's physicsBody. My problem is that when they contact each other the player sprite floats over the gap's PhysicsBody. I have set it's collisionBitMask to 0 and have made it isDynamic = false. Can anybody help?

Okay so here's my gap's code

```
    var gap = SKNode()

    gap.position = CGPoint(x: obstacle.position.x, y:  platform.position.y + 210)

    gap.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 30, height:  70))

    gap.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    gap.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false

    gap.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    gap.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Gap
    gap.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None


    gap.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    gap.physicsBody?.friction = 0

    self.addChild(gap)
```

And here's my players code

```
    let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "white.jpg")

    player = SKSpriteNode(texture: playerTexture)

    player.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)

    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)

    player.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 100 , y: self.frame.midY + 50 )

    player.physicsBody!.restitution = 0

    player.physicsBody!.friction = 0


    player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Obstacles | PhysicsCategory.Gap
    player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Obstacles | PhysicsCategory.Floor

    self.addChild(player)
```

Physics Category is

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
static let None      : UInt32 = 0
static let Obstacles : UInt32 = 0b1     // 1
static let Player    : UInt32 = 0010
static let Floor     : UInt32 = 0100
static let Gap       : UInt32 = 1000
```

}

Comment: Try setting `isDynamic = true`. You need the sprite to be dynamic for it to work with `physicsBodies`

Comment: @Nik just tried that. I still get the same result

Comment: Try to be more descriptive in your question and add code so we can see the problem

Comment: Okay I'll get to it when I get home thanks

Comment: Okay I added my player's and my gap's code, thanks for all the help so far

Comment: Your player needs to also be dynamic for collisions to work

Comment: player needs to be dynamic, the gap does not.  There may be optimization tactics in place where if an object doesn't move, it doesn't get added to the check list  (That is the entire point of dynamic,  it means objects can move)

Comment: I change my player to dynamic when I touch the screen for the first time it's just not evident in the code I've provided. I also tried setting the player to dynamic and the gap to not dynamic but I still get the same result

Comment: is didBeginContact being called at all? Is your class an SKPhysicsContactDelegate? Have you set the physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self? Can you list your PhysicsCategory definitions?

Comment: Yes didBeginContact is being called, my class is an SKPhysicsContactDelegate, and I have set the physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self. I also believe that there is something wrong with my PhysicsCategory definitions. I have now added them in my question. Thanks for the help so far!